# Exporting a png file from an `Image` object

Tags: dart

I have an instance of the `Image` class from `'package:image/image.dart'`.
How would I turn it into a `.png` file?
I tried using `.getBytes()` like this:

```dart
myPngFile.writeAsBytes(myImage.getBytes());
```

But couldn't open it with my image viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `encodePng` function from `package:image/image.dart`.
Like this:

```dart
myPngFile.writeAsBytes(encodePng(myImage));
```